In Psalm 146:4, what is the correct word--thoughts or plans?
In psalm 146:4, the word, עֶשְׁתֹּנֹתָֽיו׃ (SH 6250) is sometimes translated as "thoughts" but I believe that this is incorrect in the Hebrew. It should be rendered PLANS, not thoughts. What support is there between the choices?
One of the passages most often used to support the belief that the dead are unconscious is Psalm 146:3-4. For example, in Young's Literal Translation:

3 Trust not in princes -- in a son of man, For he hath no deliverance.
4 His spirit goeth forth, he returneth to his earth, In that day have
his thoughts perished. [YLT]


Welcome to the site, Mark.  Your question needs clarification, as it starts out as a question but ends up as your answer to it. Also, it's not clear what you mean by "In answer to your teaching..." Whose teaching is this, and what teaching is this? Can you provide a Stack link and quotes? As it is, you seem to be using the Question facility to give your opinion about a matter we are not privy to, until you provide a link that is. Do take the site Tour to see how questions are to be presented, in order to be acceptable.

This belongs as a comment or an answer. It should not be stated as a 'Question'. The site cannot be addressed as 'your teaching'. Individuals post questions and individuals post answers. Individuals should be addressed as individuals. Biblehub and Strong disagree with you and state 'thoughts' as do KJV, Green's Literal, Young's Literal, and Webster.

Hi Mark.  Welcome and I hope you enjoy and benefit from the site.  I suggest, after taking the tour, that you take a few minutes and review a few other questions and their answers.

Mark, Welcome to the Biblical Hermeneutics forum. I edited your question and the content to conform to how they should be asked here. As you can see, it typically takes some research to lay out the question clearly. Feel free to make any additional changes, but I hope my changes helped.

This word only occurs once in the Hebrew Old Testament.  Thus, this question is difficult to answer.

By definition you cannot make plans without thoughts.  But I suppose you can have thoughts without making plans but that raises the question of what kind of thoughts can you have without the desire or ability or freedom to make plans.  The idea that we remain conscious after death but our "plans" somehow cease seems to be the foundation of conscious life after death, thinking but no planning.  Personally I don't buy it.  His plans cease is synonymous with his thought cease.  Thoughts without planning is mindless thinking and I'll skip that option.

It could also be called retarded thinking.  Mentally retarded people by definition aren't into making plans.

When we die we sort of become retarded?  I'll opt out of that one.

Internal plans versus external plans?  Please.

As it stands, your question is good one. But it is unanswerable.
עֶשְׁתֹּנֹתָֽיו is a hapax legomenon. This is the only occurrence in the the OT corpus.  Brug writes (p. 498):

"Plans", appears only here, and a related word occurs in Job 12:5.
For this reason some have called it an Aramaism, but it may just be a
rare word in biblical Hebrew.  At any rate it is not a late word,
since it occurs in an eigth-century Aramaic inscription from Sefire.
(Brug, p. 498)

When we bump into hapax legomena, we rely on the versions to give us some help.  They translate as follows:

“πάντες οἱ διαλογισμοὶ αὐτῶν.” (Psalm 145:4 LXXS-T)
“omnes cogitationes eorum” (Psalm 145:4 V-LATINA)
“cogitationes eius” (Psalm 145:4 VULG-T)
”ܐ̈ܒܕܢ ܟܘܠܗ݁ܝܢ ܡܚ̈ܫܒܬܗ.“ (Psalm 146:4 PESHOT-T)

You'll notice that they go with "internal dialogues" (i.e. thoughts).  The Syriac is interesting, in that it goes with ܡܚ̈ܫܒܬܗ. This, of course, is the word, חָשַׁב (in Hebrew).  The semantic domain of that word includes both the concepts of thinking and planning:


think, [p. 363] account לבבו לא כן יחשׁב Is 10:7 not so thinketh his mind; ‏חשׁבי שׁמוֹ Mal 3:16 those thinking of his name; sq. 2 acc.
‏חשׁבנהו נגוע Is 53:4 we thought him stricken; elsewhere c. acc. + לְ
Gn 38:15 (J), 1 S 1:13, Jb 19:15, 35:2, 41:24; so, fig., of crocodile
Jb 41:19 he reckoneth iron as straw.
devise, plan, mean, c. acc. מַחֲשֶׁבֶת רָעָה Ez 38:10, ‏רעה‎ ψ 35:4, 140:3, Zc 7:10, 8:17, ‏תַּהְפֻּכ֑וֹת Pr 16:30, ‏מְזִמּוֹת‎ ψ
10:2, 21:12, ‏דִּבְרֵי מִרְמוֹת ψ 35:20, ‏אָוֶן Mi 2:1, Ez 11:2, ψ
36:5, ‏הַוּוֹת ψ 52:4; ‏ח׳ רע(ה) על devise evil against Gn 50:20 (E),
Je 48:2, Na 1:11, ‏ח׳ רעה לְ ψ 41:8, ‏ח׳ מַחֲשֶׁבֶת על Je 11:19,
18:11, 18:18, 49:30, Dn 11:25, Est 8:3, 9:25, ‏ח׳ כזאת על‎ 2 S 14:13;
c. inf. 1 S 18:25, Je 18:8, 23:27, Jb 6:26, Ne 6:2, 6:6, Est 9:24, ψ
140:5; c. ‏לבלתי‎ + Impf. 2 S 14:14 (reading ‏חוֹשֵׁב‎ for ‏וחשׁב‎ and
taking man as subj. We Dr; in this case ‏לבלתי‎ carries on ‏לֹא
יִשָּׂא‎).

(BDB, s.v. “חָשַׁב,” 362-363.)

So, since this is a hapax, it's wise to not force a meaning that cannot be substantiated. With that in mind, it is not surprising that translations go with either "plans" or "thoughts", since either meaning is just as weakly attested and there is a massive overlap in meaning of "thought/plan" nouns anyway (e.g. חָשַׁב).

Excellent answer, Epimanes! +1 Thank you for your thorough research!

Very good answer. +1.

The answer of Epimanes is very good - this should be regarded as a supplement to that.
The operative word in Ps 146:4 is עֶשְׁתֹּנָה (eshtonah, a once-only word in the OT) which the lexicons define as:

BDB "thought"
NAS "thought"
Strong's "thought"
Complete Word Study Dictionary of OT (Baker and Carpenter): "A feminine plural noun indicating a thought, a plan. It refers to ideas, imaginations, desires produced by a person while still alive."

The ancient versions translated it as follows:

LXX (200-250 BC): διαλογισμοὶ = "thought"
Jerome's vulgate (400 AD): cogitationes = "thoughts"
Peshitta and Lamsa translation of Aramaic = "thoughts"

Strong says that our word is derived from "Ashath" meaning "to think".
Context
The context provides some clues about the meaning of this word as well:

V2: I will praise the LORD while I live; I will sing praises to my God while I have my being.  This is because we are informed in Eccl 9:10, " ... for there is no work or device or knowledge or wisdom in the grave where you are going."
V5, 6: Blessed is he whose help is the God of Jacob, whose hope is in the LORD his God, ... He remains faithful forever.  This in in contradistinction to humans who come to an end and die.

Now, in English, "plans" can mean either:

internal thoughts and plans
external plans that have been set in train

Therefore, if "plans" is the translation, it should be understood as the former - internal, mental thoughts and plans and not the latter.

Internal plans versus external plans?  This is dicing words to the max.

Remember people back then weren't pondering internal plans versus external plans.  Please.
